# Data attribute value from first div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

This should be easy but I am stuck! I need to get a data attribute from the first div in html chunk obtained using ajax. The div can have other elements or text but it will always be the first item in the html chunk. The html will not contain head, body or other start elements.

Html looks like below.

```
<div data-code="US"><span style="background-color:red">test</span><br /></div>
```

The jQuery script looks like below.

```
function LoadCode(url) {
            $.get(url, function (data1) {
                var code = "";
                //code = $(data1 + ":first").data("code"); // did not work
                //code = $(data1).data("code"); // did not work
                alert(code);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$(data1).data('code');
```

Comment: Surprisingly it works even though I mentioned in the comment in the original post that it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You must get attribute from div like:

```
code = $(data1).attr("data-code");
```

Comment: It returns undefined. Why can't I use the .data() though?

Comment: what is response of data are you getting it?

Comment: I think you can't use .data() when you getting html attribute!

Comment: The response is the html snippet above

Comment: Sure, you can use data() api. I am getting a data attribute.